# iOS [Keychain Sharing]: items are no longer accessible after transitioning from Lockbox to KeychainSwift

Tags: ios, security-framework

I have items stored in ios keychain with (Lockbox).
Now I've enabled KeychainSharing to share some data with
an app extension -> the data written into keychain
before that enablement happened can no longer be retrieved. I've switched to KeychainSwift in the meanwhile.

No matter what I change accessGroup on KeychainSwift instance to I cant get to that nameless legacy private keychain.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Lockbox apparently adds a bundle identifier as a prefix to the keys
while KeychainSwift does not